# Firebase Cloud Messaging plugin not working redirected HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with the Firebase Cordova Plugin.

I get notifications when my app runs the file index.html. But when `window.location.href` is changed, the notifications do not work. What am I doing wrong?

`onDeviceReady` function in file index.js:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {

if(window.localStorage.getItem("token") == null)
    {window.localStorage.setItem("token", "")};
setTimeout(getTheToken, 1000);

function getTheToken() {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("token") == ""){
        FCMPlugin.getToken(
            function (token) {
                if (token == null) {
                    console.log("null token");
                    setTimeout(getTheToken, 1000);
                    navigator.notification.alert("Bucle"); // Bucle === Loop
                } else {
                    console.log("I got the token: " + token);                    
                    window.localStorage.setItem("token", token);   
                    alert("Ya tengo Token" + token);                
                }
            },
            function (err) {
                alert('error retrieving token: ' + err);
            }
        );
    }
}

FCMPlugin.onNotification(
    function(data){
        if(data.wasTapped){
            //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
            alert("Tapped: " +  JSON.stringify(data) );
        }else{
            //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
            alert("Not tapped: " + JSON.stringify(data) );
        }
    },
    function(msg){
        alert('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
        console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
    },
    function(err){
        alert('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
        console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
    }
);
app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
```

I have another JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#entrar").on("click",function(e){
        var identificador = $("#asociado_id").val();
        var token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
        login(identificador, token, "#entrar");

    });
});
```

Above, the login function redirects to another page if `identificador` exists.

```
success: function(respuesta) {
                if(respuesta.tk == "true"){
                   window.localStorage.setItem("login", "true");
                   window.location.href = "main.html";
```

In the redirected page, the notifications do not arrive. That page is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/velocity.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_menu.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
```

If the `<script cordova.js>` is activated (uncommented) in the page, the application enters the loop (bucle).

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem with order of code

Try move **FCMPlugin.onNotification(...);** just after of **FCMPlugin.getToken(...);**

This is my **index.js** file that i use when i want my app had Push Notification with FCM. I hope help you.

```
var app = {

initialize: function () {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.onBackKeyDown, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function () {

    app.notificacionesPush();


},

notificacionesPush: function () {

    FCMPlugin.getToken(
            function (token) {

                var obj = {"token": token};

                Ajax("http://MI-URL/webservice.php", obj, function (data) {
                    if (data.code === "OK")
                        console.info("Token de Dispositivo registrado correctamente");
                    else
                        console.info("Error en registro de Token");

                }, function () {
                    console.warn("Error en registro de Token");
                });
            },
            function (err) {
                console.warn('error retrieving token: ' + err);
            }
    );


    FCMPlugin.onNotification(
            function (data) {
                if (data.wasTapped) {
                    console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
                } else {
                    console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            },
            function (msg) {
                console.info('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
            },
            function (err) {
                console.info('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
            }
    );
},}; app.initialize();
```

Comment: The problem is when change page... the second page not working push notifications, because the file index.js is declared on index.html